# How is throughput value is calculating in summary report when we have samples more than 1?

Tags: jmeter

I have create a test plan setting no. of threads= 1 ramp-up period= 1 and loop count = 1

If i want to verify throughput value of 2nd label i am using this formula 2/5 means (no.of samples / average time) which results in 0.4 ms but the value in jmeter is showing as 4.9/min. And how are the last two rows of summary report are calculating which include labels of Test(it is my transaction controller) and Total. Please explain with formula. The image of my summary report is in the given link.
[summary report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viA8W.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong formula, according to [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

> **Throughput** is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
>   The formula is: `Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).`

So you should be dividing the number of requests not by average response time, but by the whole duration of the test.

If you want to exclude some Samplers which are "not interesting" using [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) where you can specify the label(s) of the sampler(s) you would like to get metrics for.

Filter Results Tool can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

Comment: the total time is 267 ms of my test which is the sum of all samples time of all label but when i divide 2/267 it will give 0.007490636704119850187265917603 and after multiplying this value by 1000 for converting in to sec it will give7.4906367041198501872659176029963 , but this value is still not matching with my jmeter value of throughput which is 4.9 / min of 2nd label